# What is the most suitable alternative for Linked List?

Tags: c, linked-list, embedded, misra, autosar

I am working on Embedded C, Task related implementation in OS. I have implemented the [Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). Now it needs to minimize the use of pointers to satisfy [MISRA C](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023981/Introduction-to-MISRA-C), in my present implementation I am searching for the best alternative for the Linked List, in Embedded OS for task operation.

Comment: I need to satisfy MISRAC, hence minimum use of Pointers is suggested. I thought of using a linked list over a static array. The only difference is that instead of pointer to a dynamically allocated chunck of memory, I use a pointer to an elementet inside the array.

Comment: The embedded operating systems of today, is often bigger than the full operating systems of yesterday. Take, for example, the [Amiga 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_500) and its [AmigaOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS), the computer had unexpanded 512 *kilo*-byte of RAM and no FLASH or other non-volatile memory. The operating system used linked lists *extensively*, basically for everything in the system, and a lot of other pointers as well. What I'm trying to say is that trying to reduce the number of pointers or linked lists is probably not really needed.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking about trying to reduce the amount of memory used? Because when designing and coding operating system kernels pointers are not really something you can (or should) avoid.

Comment: The main alternative to a linked list of things would be an array of things.

Comment: What I am trying to convience is, I am developing the Automotive product under the ISO26262 safety standard, in this a sugesstion given, to maintain the ASIL standard that, a Os developement code should aviod uses of pointer. In my code I have indentified that Linklisting can be replaced to achieve  this objective.

Comment: Be careful how you define *pointer*. After all, what is it that points to the first member of an array? I haven't read the standard, but I know the government, and the pedantic standards that the blind dictate to the blind. It would seem the thrust of the requirement is to minimize the potential for type/size mismatch in the use of general pointers compared to the type enforced by using an array. Make sure you understand what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: "Avoid pointers" is a stupid requirement, it is just like saying "avoid integers".  If you find that in a safety standard it only means that the person who wrote that standard is incompetent, period. I can say this because I work in this area of application and read these standards all the time You will not find such a requirement in MISRA-C because that's a serious standard written by professionals. You will however find such a requirement in 61508/26262 because it is a muppet standard written by bureaucrats.

Comment: That is check, for example 61508-7 C.2.6.6 "limited use of pointers". There's just some mumbling about pointer arithmetic. No sound rationale, but most notably _there are no sources or references for the rule_!!! Meaning some standard ISO muppet invented this requirement, not a professional. The rule is based on said muppet's personal, subjective opinions and not on an authority nor on scientific proof. Instead of listening to these standards _use common sense_ and spend your time on real safety issues instead.

Comment: There is no language "Embedded C".

Comment: The MISRA rule is about using limited **operations on** pointers, not pointers themselves (which was nonsense in C)

Comment: @Olaf The limited use pointers nonsense comes from IEC 61508. MISRA tries to sate that standard, which is the explanation for why there are a couple of MISRA rules that stand out as stupid. Specifically, the rule banning pointer arithmetic (which has been somewhat fixed in MISRA 2012) and the rule about multiple return statements (demoted to advisory in 2012). Both rules completely lacked rationale, which is because they are directly inherited from 61508, which in turn completely lacks rationale or sources for the very same rules.

Comment: This question should not be down voted. This is a very relevant question. The MISRA rules stem from the problems surrounding pointers and memory allocation, namely (1) Dereferencing NULL on a live system (i.e. a car), (2) Malloc'ing until you run out of memory on your microcontroller (again not good for a car on the road). This question has strong merit, and criticisms of muppets are with prejudice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be easy to use a static array of structures to completely avoid pointers (you'd just use array indexes and not pointers). This has both advantages and disadvantages.

The disadvantages are:

- you have to implement your own allocator (to allocate and free "array elements" within the static array)
- the memory used for the array can't be used for any other purpose when it's not being used for the linked list
- you have to determine a "max. number of elements that could possibly be needed"
- it has all the same problems as pointers. E.g. you can access an array element that was freed, free the same array element multiple times, use an index that's out of bounds (including the equivalent of `NULL` if you decide to do something like use `-1` to represent `NULL_ELEMENT`), etc.

The advantages are:

- by implementing your own allocator you can avoid the mistakes caused by `malloc()`, including (e.g.) checking something isn't already free when freeing it and returning an error instead of trashing your own metadata
- allocation can typically be simpler/faster, because you're only allocating/freeing one "thing" (array element) at a time and don't need to worry about allocating/freeing a variable number of contiguous "things" (bytes) at a time
- entries in your list are more likely to be closer (in memory) to each other (unlike for `malloc()` where your entries are scattered among everything else you allocate), and this can improve performance (cache locality)
- you have a "max. number of elements that could possibly be needed" to make it far easier to track down problems like (e.g.) memory leaks; and (where memory is limited) make it easier to determine things like worst case memory footprint
- it satisfies pointless requirements (like "no pointers") despite not avoiding anything these requirements are intended to avoid

Comment: The OP won't be able to use `malloc` anyway, that function is forbidden by MISRA C rules.

Comment: `you have to determine a "max. number of elements that could possibly be needed"` => you can start with small array (eg : 4 items) and when you reach that limit what you allocate a new array and increase the size (eg : you double it). This is how dynamic lists are usually implement.

Comment: @tigrou: You can't increase the size of a statically allocated array at run-time. Don't forget that OP can't use pointers or `malloc()` (or `realloc()`), and therefore can't do "dynamically allocated memory used for an array".

Comment: I  forget to explain one crucial step : once the new array has been created, you the values of the old array are copied into the new one(this is, of course, a O(n) operation but it does not occurs at each insertion).

Answer (score 1):

> Now it needs to minimize the use of pointers to satisfy MISRA C

I used to work with some embedded engineers. They built low-end (and high-end) routers and gateways. Rather than dynamically allocating memory, they used fixed buffers provisioned at boot. They then tracked indexes into the array of provisioned buffers.

Static arrays and indexes begs for a Cursor data structure. Your first search hit is [Cursor Implementation of Linked Lists from 
Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++, 2nd ed. by Mark Weiss](http://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ssdavis/60/CursorList.pdf). (I actually used that book in college years ago).

Comment: Quite lovely if you ask me. If this is preallocated on the heap at startup, even better.